# Which class provides the implementation for getRequestDispatcher() method

Tags: java, servlets

The `getRequestDispatcher()` method of `ServletRequest` *interface* returns the object of `RequestDispatcher`.

I know that `getRequestDispatcher()` method is in the *Interface* `ServletRequest`. As it is an *interface*, it won't define the method.

Furthermore, this *interface* is again inherited in another *interface* `HttpServletRequest`. But being an interface, it won't define its methods.

Now, after carefully checking the JavaDocs, I could not find any class that implemented either of these two interfaces, and defined the `getRequestDispatcher()` method.

So I was wondering where did they define this method

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was searching for this question for a really long time. It is great that you have asked it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class which implements is `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade` , in case of **TOMCAT** container.
The implementation is basically dependent on containers & every container has its own implementation adhering to the J2EE Specs.

Use the below code to check the implementation class :-

```
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(httpServletRequest.getClass());
    }
}
```

Output :- `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade`

You can see this class Offical Doc [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/RequestFacade.html), and can check that it has implemented the `interface javax.servlet.ServletRequest` and its methods like `getRequestDispatcher()` etc.

Comment: public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res) throws IOException,ServletException {  
    res.setContentType("text/html");  
    PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();  
    out.print("<html><body>");  
    out.print(req.getClass());  
    out.print("</body></html>");  
    }  

Output:- `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade`  Tried with this code, gave a different class name

Comment: The OP was asking about ServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher(), not ServletContext#getRequestDispatcher(). @probuddhasingha Why did you accept the answer?

Comment: @probuddhasingha that class `org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade` is correct, it is the implementation of `javax.servlet.ServletRequest`

Comment: thats what got me confused. @hzpz thanks for clarifying it !!

Answer (score 3):

Each container (Tomcat, Jetty, etc.) has its own class that implements HttpServletRequest. This class implements all the methods of the interface. An instance of this class is passed by the container to your servlet.

If you're really curious about it, add

```
System.out.println(request.getClass());
```

to your servlet, and you'll know the name of the concrete class.

But really, you don't need to know about it. All you need to know is that it implements the HttpServletRequest interface and thus fulfills the contract described in the javadoc and the specifications.

Answer (score 0):

For jetty v6 it is `org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler` and its return `org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher` instance.

And this is how `forward` from Dispatcher works there:

1. It took original request, replace request url with new value
2. Clear output stream.
3. Execute request-responce pair via context.handle(request, responce)
4. Reset original value of request url for request.